# Rails pass params with post or redirect with 301?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a link that passes a parameter to the show action of my post:

```
<%= link_to post_show_path( user.id, ref: user.ref ) do %>
  go to post
<% end %>
```

But this creates the URL: localhost:3000/post?ref=1445461

Obviously, this will create duplications which kills my SEO. I want to pass that reference to the controller but not show it on the URL. I tried using method post without success:

```
<%= link_to post_show_path( user.id), ref: user.ref, method: :post do %>
 go to post
<% end %>
```

It doesn't pass params[:ref]

So first, am I doing it wrong? Is my syntax wrong? and if not, do I have other alternatives? if yes, could you please write it down for me?

I was thinking of doing a 301 redirect, but putting a redirect to the same show action inside the show action obviously creates a loop. I prefer not to pass through another action just to get to the "show" action.

So what do I do? :)

Answer (score 0):

By default, `html` link elements do not `post`. If you need to have a link to be able to mimic the `post` request, then you can use `button_to` helper provided by `rails`. Even though `button_to` generates a button tag, you could use some css styling and make it look like a link.

Refer to [UrlHelper#button_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) for more info.

Comment: I was considering this, but it's really not elegant. I am trying to find a more appropriate way ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `ref` param into the path:

```
<%= link_to "go to post", post_show_path(user.id, ref: user.ref), method: :post %>
```

But if your only concern is SEO duplication, you can as well stick with a GET request and use the [`rel=nofollow` directive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nofollow):

```
<%= link_to "go to post", post_show_path(user.id, ref: user.ref), rel: "nofollow" %>
```

**Update:** if what you need is having multiple urls pointing to the same page (from the SEO point of view), then you **may use the canonical URL**, possibly also with a 301 redirect, as described e.g. [here](http://www.wordtracker.com/academy/learn-seo/technical-guides/seo-clean-urls) or [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en). Google (and others) will then index this page as a single page although multiple urls would point to it.

Comment: That would not work for me. If I add no follow on those links, then none of those linked pages will get indexed.

Comment: Aha, I think I see now what you mean... please see my updated answer.